# How to input a CSS class with JavaScript to affect another function

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen

I have gone at a lot of informative sites in order to find answer but no luck so far. Thus now asking here.

---

#### CSS Class

```
.toppy {
  :-webkit-full-screen {position: relative; top: -1310;}
  :-moz-full-screen {position: relative; top: -1310;}
  :-ms-fullscreen {position: relative; top: -1310;}
  fullscreen {position: relative; top: -1310;}
}
```

---

#### JS Input

```
window.onscroll = function() {mss()};

function mss() {
  var posi = document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById("toppy").style.top = -posi;
}
```

Depending on a position on a web page, this should give the value (posi). Negatived as CSS works on that way, and trying to update CSS with style(top) value (posi). However, no updating.

---

#### JS into which CSS influences

```
function FullScreen()  {  .... code .... }
```

CSS affects to this. If CSS has defined without class `.toppy`, function `FullScreen` works nicely opening full screen with the CSS's pre-set values (-1310) at the position downwards from the top.

---

But why is CSS's style property top not being updated by JS input function and therefore changing the position of the `FullScreen` to open at? My goal is to obtain the full screen to be opened at its current position on page. Some browsers do this automatically, some do not. Thus needing coding.

Or does one have to define a variable in css (e.g. `var(--posi)`) and proceed on this way but I do not have a real clue how to do that?

Many thanks for replies!

---

**Update**:

Thanks for the points. Valid ones. However, as the problem remains, I think the issue here is how to link a css to certain js being the case paricularry with this fullscreen. If I had two identical js fullscreen (expect function name), how would I define above kind of css to one js and another css to another js? As for me, it seems that css for fullscreen is (defined as above) not accepting any id or class tags, or I do not know how to link id to js? Syntaxing? Regards!

Comment: You can use `-100vh` in your CSS, that's the negative entire viewport height. As for your question, while you can change CSS *rules*, people usually change elements' styles directly. Edit: I'm pretty sure you need to add a unit: `-posi + "px"`

Comment: document.getElementById("toppy") should not work as you have defined toppy as class not as ID